# Use parent child relation when I have more than 100,000 children on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Can I use this way
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/parent-join.html
When I have more than 100,000 children for each parent

Answer (score 0):

I could not find information about that limit in specific, but I think you could have problems for many reasons.

- Elasticsearch [warns](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-has-child-query.html#query-dsl-has-child-query) about the low performance of this type of mapping
- There is a `max_children` to return in a query that defaults to 10, probably will blow before the 100k
- For nested objects the max is 10,000 this suggests the max for children docs will be similar
- According to the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html#_parent_join_restrictions) , all the children must be indexed on the same shard

I would recommend to re-check your requirements and consider a flat schema. I can't say much more without knowing the data.

Comment: What is the best way for my cases 
for example when I have two tables
1- schools (parent) 2- students (child) has about 100.000
create one index including information student and school in the same document without Join datatype
example (students index) : student ID,student name,student age,student level,school ID,school name,school address
and I need to create another index for schools, so we can get the schools information
example (schools index): school ID, school name, school address.
we don't need to modify the tables frequently, just need them as an archive, or use join

Comment: You can create many indices. One for students, and one for schools and store the school information you need on each student. Depending on how are you exploring your data you can save all the school data on each student or just the id and then making a second query to fetch the school data.

Comment: But in general you want to store all the data as you can on each document,  it doesnt matter if you duplicate data. This will make your queries faster

Comment: Remember documents store vs SQL database is the first one is "view oriented and atomic" and the second one "relationship oriented", so in Elasticsearch you want to adapt your documents to the queries you will make, not the oposite

Comment: I prefer to add all fields (students-schools) on one document, so when I need to get only schools I can use aggregation ("aggs") for that, what you think
Thank you,

Comment: Depends on the views you want to generate. But sure if your views are centered on the students that approach is a good idea. You can use aggs to get the schools